# Error returning JSON formed in yii controller in android

Tags: android, json, yii

I have successfully created a JSON API in yii which I validated on http://jsonlint.com/ and used in the web application using jquery $.getJSON();

Everything was working fine till now

but when I access the same API in my android application using the same URL it gives me error

```
07-05 00:57:45.548: E/JSON Parser(28866): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

so I tried once more and copy the all JSON generated by yii into a file and named it as mydata.json and try to get this JSON from my android app and yes everything is working fine

so I concluded that there something might wrong with yii but I am unable to figure out that my method for API generation is

```
public function actionMycontroller{
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
            $json="    all my json generation code";
            echo json_encode($json);
        Yii::app()->end();  
 }
```

what should I do now to debug my error ?

Answer (score 3):

`<!DOCTYPE` indicates that your service is **NOT** outputting pure json. It's probably gotten wrapped in an html wrapper, e.g. you've actually got

```
<!DOCTYPE ...>
<html>
<body>
...json goes here...
</body>
</html>
```

in other words, your controller is trying to spit out a full-blown HTML page, not just the json response that should be getting output.

Comment: but the same url is working fine on the web and when I access url directly it works fine

Comment: yes, because you're viewing it in a browser, which will render all of the html. try a "view source" and you'll see all the html scafffolding which the json decoder CANNOT ignore.

Comment: I am amazed view source is not there for the particular tab but yes I can inspect element and you are right there are html tags there

Comment: never ever trust what your browser's showing you, because its job is to translate what it's given. If it translates wrong, it won't warn you, it'll just pretend it did the right thing. always check 'view source' or whatever first.

Comment: @BCT Can you let us know, what caused that extra HTML? Because from the action code you posted there should not be any HTML rendered. Was it maybe a `CWebLogRoute` or a `CProfileLogRoute` you had configured or something?